# Any other way to make beacon ranging work in background?

Tags: ios, background, ibeacon

I am setting allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates to true and UIBackgroundModes to location in info.plist. But Apple has rejected my app because of UIBackgroundModes flag. Is there any other way to get beacon ranging work in background?

I see that the moment I put app to background, it cannot range beacons. I have tried running background task. But that helps beacon ranging only for 3 minutes.

Please suggest an alternate solution.

Comment: You cannot range in the background indefinitely

Comment: You should explain them to make the app validate. I have several apps on the store, which have been previously rejected